# How to make a cookie's expiration date later with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I often connect a website with a session cookie which expires after a few hours. This is annoying because I am required to re-login very often.

The cookie is `HTTPOnly`, thus I cannot manipulate it with Javscript Console.

**How to, manually, in Chrome, make its expiration date to a later date?**

Here is how I can see the cookie:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  By flagging the cookie **HttpOnly**, makes it inaccessible to JavaScript in the browser.  Any method you want to use in the browser (including addons) use JavaScript.

From [What is an HttpOnly Cookie?](https://www.cookiepro.com/knowledge/httponly-cookie/)

> An HttpOnly Cookie is a tag added to a browser cookie that prevents client-side scripts from accessing data. It provides a gate that prevents the specialized cookie from being accessed by anything other than the server.  Using the HttpOnly tag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of client-side scripts accessing the protected cookie, thus making these cookies more secure.

Just say that you were able to change its expiry time, it will not work on most decent sites, certainly not on mine.  Because on every request for a page, I check the cookie and correct it.  Typically I have encrypted information in to protect vital information.

Your best bet is to contact the website owner and explain why it would be nice to expand the expiry time.